# How to get the instance of the text field which has triggers the focus listener in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I have a **form** consisting of three `text fields`. When the form is submitted, I validate each text field value to ensure it meets specific conditions. If a value is invalid, I change the `border color` of the respective text field to **red**. Now, I want to update the border color back to black if the user selects a text field and attempts to modify its value.

To streamline the process for all text fields, I aim to attach the same `change listener` to each one. However, the challenge lies in obtaining a **reference** to each text field so that I can specifically target it within the listener.

```
 keyWord.focusedProperty().addListener(textFieldFocusListener);
 date.focusedProperty().addListener(textFieldFocusListener);
 location.focusedProperty().addListener(textFieldFocusListener);

 ChangeListener<Boolean> textFieldFocusListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        // Change the border color of the text field to black if it is selected/focused

     };
```

Comment: Totally out of context: The general pattern is to change the border color only if user starts typing some thing. Merely removing the alerts(border) on just focus is not a great UX. Ofcourse this varies based on your individual requirements. But I just want to say about that :). In this case you need to add the listener on textProperty() instead of focusedProperty().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just write a method to create and register a listener for each text field?

```
private void addListenerToTextField(TextField textField) {
    textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // do whatever you need with textField
    });
}
```

Which scales to multiple text fields in the same way

```
addListenerToTextField(keyWord);
addListenerToTextField(date);
addListenerToTextField(location);
```

or

```
Stream.of(keyWord, date, location).forEach(this::addListenerToTextField);
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was thinking of the hard possible solution :)

Comment: @Starnec The approach in this answer is superior, but just want to point out that with your original approach you could do `(TextField) ((ReadOnlyProperty<?>) observable).getBean()`. But again, as shown in this answer, you should definitely prefer adding a unique listener to each text field where the context gives you a reference to the text field directly (not least because it avoids a bunch of casts).